# Constrained function's input-output give unexpected error

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function with an output type constrained by the input type.
Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do :

```
function dummy<T extends string | number>(input: T) : T {
  let result: T

  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    result = 'foo'
  } else {
    result = 1
  }

  return result
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'string' is assignable
> to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a
> different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.

I am not sure how to fix this, I was expecting the type T to collapse to string or number within the scope of the if statement, which seems to not be the case.

Please note that in the actual function, there are error checks and parsing inside each if statements, handled before the final return, meaning I cannot just return from inside.

Comment: Your code isn't properly typed because TS will infer `T` to be a string or number [*literal type*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  You can write the typings properly but TS isn't smart enough to properly check the implementation; probably overloads are the standard way to do this, you could also use conditional types.  All of this is shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzxgQN). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I tried avoiding overload since in the actual function there would be 5 overloads.
I figured there would be a better way to do it.
Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Sorry to reiterate but I'm not sure from your comment: Should I go ahead and write up an answer explaining?  Or did I miss something about the question?

Comment: Your answer was enough, I was hoping there would be a way to do that without overloads, it seems there is not.

Comment: Note that I also showed using a conditional type, did you see that?  I will write up an actual answer (these comments are just me trying to get clarification; they don't count as an answer for Stack Overflow purposes and they could get deleted at any time)

Comment: Oh ok.
Yes, I saw the second option, but I try to avoid "as" statements whenever possible.

Comment: Overloads are just as unsafe as using `as`.  If you want you could write a single generic overloaded call signature and then you don't need `as` in the body of the function, but you're not gaining safety by doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is correct to warn you that returning `"foo"` or `1` is not guaranteed to satisfy the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) return type `T`.  String and number [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) exist, so if you call `dummy(123)` then `T` will be inferred as `123`, and the return value of `1` is not assignable to `123`.  This could lead to runtime errors, as shown here:

```
function dummy<T extends string | number>(input: T): T {
    let result: T
    if (typeof input === 'string') { result = 'foo' } else { result = 1 }
    return result
}

const oops = dummy("abc");
//     ^? const oops: "abc" 
const obj = { abc: 123, def: 456 };
const num = obj[oops];
//    ^? const num: number

num.toFixed() // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! num is undefined
```

Here the compiler believes that `oops` is of type `"abc"`, which means it allows indexing into an object with a key of `"abc"`, which leads to problems.

You can fix your typings several ways, but the compiler can't really verify that your implementation will satisfy those typings.

---

One way is to change the function's return type from `T` to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that will output `string` if `T extends string` and `number` otherwise, so that even if `T` is narrower than `string` or `number` it will still be the right type:

```
declare function dummy<T extends string | number>(
  input: T
): T extends string ? string : number; 

const str = dummy("abc");
// const str: string 
const num = dummy(123);
// const num: number
```

That now works from the caller's side.  The compiler will still complain about the implementation, though, because it can't follow the logic.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the relevant feature request to support this better. For now you'll need to use some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the warning:

```
function dummy<T extends string | number>(input: T): T extends string ? string : number {
    let result: T extends string ? string : number;
    if (typeof input === 'string') {
        result = 'foo' as typeof result // <-- assert
    } else {
        result = 1 as typeof result // <-- assert
    }
    return result
}
```

---

Another way is to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) your function with multiple call signatures:

```
declare function dummy(input: string): string;
declare function dummy(input: number): number;

const str = dummy("abc");
// const str: string
const num = dummy(123);
// const num: number
```

Again, that works from the caller's side. The implementation will not give you a compiler error, but that's a false sense of security, since the compiler really isn't verifying that the right output goes with the right input:

```
function dummy(input: string): string;
function dummy(input: number): number;
function dummy(input: string | number) {
    let result: string | number;
    if (typeof input === 'string') {
        result = 'foo' // okay, but result = 1 would also be "okay" here
    } else {
        result = 1 // okay, but result = "foo" would also be "okay" here
    }
    return result
}
```

---

You could also use both approaches, using a single generic overload call signature:

```
// call signature is generic
function dummy<T extends string | number>(
    input: T
): T extends string ? string : number;

// implementation is not
function dummy(input: string | number) {
    let result: string | number;
    if (typeof input === 'string') {
        result = 'foo';
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result
}
```

Like the others, this isn't type safe (you could alter `typeof input === 'string'` to `typeof input !== 'string'` and the compiler won't notice), but it might be more convenient.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRATmg9mgklAwtmhPAC5IDeAsAFC1INIBmArsGQJabBIAmLYMAE8APABUkEAB6kIwXlCRRSaDsADmSAD5JgAgEYQ0APgAUamC1IAuJGICUtidRqM3SADYRyxKCw82drT07gwcTEimpEIwEJgRFlZIALypSADkyqoa6faUIaFuvv7kyRlMmJjpBe4AvpIeUMguhe7FASlIAIw1brXBroXEpCxoPO2kNf10gwzw3MpIlTCKZfyCQqYARCD68Fv2ANw1APQn7gB6APxI88CLy1C2O3tbSDV3D-oAVp0USLt4LYugAmADMABo+BAmLYACwAVgAbEhasdZrcFuQ9GBOpgfgBtR4AXXRbjObmun2xAlsOMMaBqKiElF0AgAdKRMAAxDhSCC8Ux5erwECkeAAC0iEDy-0+mC87I8mHUphlqMOSApaDYpA4kEkGGwA2mtFAkFgCGQvKkAHkAG4eXj5GZuVjsPXcPgCYTmYCWQJZNTqRxKFTBsmMd2cL3rX2JQL0oyhpNoSMMaOenhxzYJ2xBjTaNlgBmy3qMLw+aAlfPhws6VPp9zhSLRWLxJAJlJpTJ19S5F2tIrVjpldIVKpa87ATBVkAeDwstvISUkADWAqQAHcIAuoaQJZgWOoJeWGPVd01B0OGBNOj0MX0z0hhqNxiPJhjpm5qWG0J0c22QEDibClfyyWtsnUD4sWLACfU2UEwSOU5zl-HE6QMIxaFNGhzWgOBECQG1CHkDgs3nF0akzLhswQ8RJBkOQFD-YMi1TMw8zsUMJGkWR5EUAtNBuISkEwksjGvUJKxfD8nEY-iWNEkS+zE4sGSbNwWyiGI4gSf0klSMchIHFob1kvxR3KSp0gBRRlw7O8KXnKBMF0WdZPnRckGXW4JXXTcdwXZ8L0aZpn2HSzSm6OyfN0xyPxCgZWlfMYLJKKYYPucgsngjYgNeFCMTA2CINYjQssWHE8t9JCivJNDYIw9TsJmXCBnwy0iJtAAhWcJQ4KApRcai2BjOiNgYvjmME1SGywkxTGfLixBqHiFJm8rhK2tTGxqUaPVo718q40T5oktAy0fCtvHSgJILY86NOWiIdPbfSA27Yy+1MiLGDvMcJ3STTGFCq8zJvAHuhB89n1S98osyjFwJUGrNhefZ6sYErsr-B6KuRpqBDR0w6tAxrcea1MTVoIA)